# gdb and makefile

Tags: c, networking, makefile, gdb

hello everyone
i try to debug a program, which have been installed by makefile.
it have a binary file of OpenDPI_demo.o and a shell shellscript OpenDPI_demo.
when i gdb OpenDPI_demo.o,i have a problem. i can't run it. the error is:

```
Starting program: /home/lx/ntop/test/opendpi/src/examples/OpenDPI_demo/OpenDPI_demo.o 
/bin/bash: /home/lx/ntop/test/opendpi/src/examples/OpenDPI_demo/OpenDPI_demo.o：can't execute the binary file.
```

please tell me why. actually i can run the program by ./OpenDPI_demo.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another example of difficulties encountered with programs using libtool.

the file `OpenDPI_demo` alongside `OpenDPI_demo.o` is actually, as you said, a shell script which wraps the execution of the real compiled file, probably in `.libs/OpenDPI_demo`.

libtool needs this wrapper to adjust the runtime library paths and such so that you can execute the program transparently, as if it was actually installed on your system.

The way to correctly debug this application is not

```
/home/lx/ntop/test/opendpi $ gdb src/examples/OpenDPI_demo/.libs/OpenDPI_demo
```

but rather using `libtool --mode=execute` on the shell script, like the following (it's an example):

```
/home/lx/ntop/test/opendpi $ ./libtool --mode=execute gdb --args \
  src/examples/OpenDPI_demo/OpenDPI_demo -f capture.pcap
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the extension, the file is **an object file**. It is used by the linker (alongside other object files) to produce an executable. It's the real executable the one you want to run/debug.

Comment: thank your answer, i have edited it, maybe i don't say it clear.

Comment: thank you, actually i find the executable-file in a hide directory in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use

```
gdb OpenDPI_demo
```

instead

In your makefile if it depens on the object, make it depend on OpenDPI_demo, e.g.

Comment: I suspect it won't do what you expect, though. When you want to use gdb interactively, it won't work nicely unless you have a fully functional tty

Comment: thank you, actually i find the executable-file in a hide directory in the end.